# Not able to pull outerHeight and put it as 'min-height'

Tags: jquery

Basically I need div carousel-services-image have the same height as div carousel-services-content. But for some reason the script doesn't add min-height to div carousel-services-image at all.

```js
function carouselService() {
  $('carousel-services-item').each(function() {
    var ths = $(this),
        thsh = ths.find('.carousel-services-content').outerHeight();
        ths.find('.carousel-services-image').css('min-height', thsh);
  });
}
carouselService();
```

```html
<div class="carousel-services-item">
  <div class="carousel-services-content">
      <div class="carousel-services-composition">
        <div class="carousel-logo"><img src="img/nea-logo-black.png" alt="NEA"></div>
        <h3 class="h3">Service Dos.</h3>
        <ul class="carousel-services-list">
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor. #1 - <strong>50 <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></strong></li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor. #2 - <strong>50 <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></strong></li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor. #3 - <strong>50 <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></strong></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="button button-white">List of Services</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-services-image" style="background-image: url(img/banner2.jpg);min-height: 350px;"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1st : be sure to include jquery

2nd : you forgot the `.` before `carousel-services-item` class

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  carouselService();
});
  
function carouselService() {
  $('.carousel-services-item').each(function() {
    var ths = $(this),
        thsh = ths.find('.carousel-services-content').outerHeight();
        ths.find('.carousel-services-image').css('min-height', thsh +'px');
        
        
        //For check
        alert(ths.find('.carousel-services-image').css('min-height'));
  });
}
```

```css
.carousel-services-image{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-services-item">
  <div class="carousel-services-content">
      <div class="carousel-services-composition">
        <div class="carousel-logo"><!--<img src="img/nea-logo-black.png" alt="NEA">--></div>
        <h3 class="h3">Service Dos.</h3>
        <ul class="carousel-services-list">
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor. #1 - <strong>50 <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></strong></li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor. #2 - <strong>50 <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></strong></li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor. #3 - <strong>50 <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></strong></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="button button-white">List of Services</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-services-image" style="min-height: 350px;"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't notice that little dot.

Comment: @IliaBocharov You're welcome .sometimes small things make a big problems . Have a great day :-)   .. And please don't forget to accept the answer